# How to solve an autonomous system of linear ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have:

$$ \begin{aligned} x_1' &= 0.03 x_1 + x_2\\  x_2' &= 0.05 x_2 \end{aligned} $$

Solving this should be easy, by doing the following:

$$x_1''=0.03x_1'+x_2'\\
x_2'=0.05x_2$$

$$x_1''=0.03x_1'+0.05x_2\\
x_2'=0.05x_2$$

but the top ODE is not solvable. Then trying:

$$x_1'=0.03x_1+x_2\\
x_2'=0.05x_2$$

$$x_1'=0.03x_1+x_2\\
x_2=0.025x_2^2+C$$

I find constant $C$ from the initial conditions, and put it $C=100$. But, then

$$x_1'=0.03x_1+x_2\\
x_2=0.025x_2^2+100$$

$$x_1'=0.03x_1+0.025x_2^2+100\\
x_2=0.025x_2^2+100$$

Again, can't separate the two from one another. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain $x_2$ from the second equation, namely $x_2(t)= c_1 e^{0.05 t}$, where $c_1$ comes from initial conditions. Now, the first equation becomes
$$
x_1'(t) = 0.03x_1(t) + c_1 e^{0.05 t},
$$

which is a linear equation that is easily solved to get
$$
x_1(t)= 50 c_1 e^{0.05 t} + c_2 e^{0.03 t}.
$$

Again, $c_2$ is computed from initial conditions.

Comment: Indeed, I considered the second equation of having a second variable instead. Thanks

Comment: @Luthier415Hz Even in more complicated situations, if you have a system of linear differential equations in the form $X' = A X$, you can write down the exact solution based on the Jordan canonical form of matrix $A$ (or its eigenvalues/eigenvectors).

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Comment: It was the last in fact that I didn't get. You  have $x_1'=0.03x_1+c_1e^{0.05t}$. So how do you integrate this? It is after all the same as $x_1'-0.03x_1=c_1e^{0.05t}$ . In fact this is called the D'Alemberts equation.

Comment: If the equation was just $x_1' - 0.03 x_1=$, this is called homogeneous as the rhs is zero, the solution would be $c_2 e^{0.03 t}$. Since the rhs is an exponential, we seek an exponential particular solution and add it to the homogenous solution.

Comment: Okey, got it. Thanks, so we solve it in the same way as inhomogeneous second order ODEs.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz yes, it is the same principle.